# Spatial audio with Agora on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm trying to use Agora.io voice chat module in my projet, I've managed to implement the voice thanks to their tuto but I can't seem to find a way to add audio spatialization. I tried using some functions: SetRemoteVoicePosition() and EnableSoundPositionIndication() but it's not working.

```
     void Update()
        {
            mRtcEngine.GetAudioEffectManager().SetRemoteVoicePosition(17, 0, 80);
        }
    
        public void JoinChannel()
        {
            string channelName = mChannelNameInputField.text.Trim();
    
            Debug.Log(string.Format("tap joinChannel with channel name {0}", channelName));
    
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelName))
            {
                return;
            }
    
            
            mRtcEngine.EnableSoundPositionIndication(true);
            //mRtcEngine.GetAudioEffectManager().SetRemoteVoicePosition(17, 0, 80);
            mRtcEngine.JoinChannel(channelName, "extra", 7);
           
        }
```

If someone could help me understand what I'm not doing or doing wrong please, it would be great !

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at this sample github project for some reference:

https://github.com/AgoraIO/Voice-Call-for-Mobile-Gaming/tree/master/Advanced-Voice-Call-for-Gaming/Spacewar-with-AMG-Voice-SDK-Unity